# Unable to send a request from React to Spring Boot when accessing the app from non-local machine

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have my frontend React app running on localhost:3000 and my Spring Boot backend server running on localhost:8080. Everything works perfectly when I access the app from the MacBook that's hosting the React and Spring boot servers (works both in Chrome and Safari). However, when I access it from devices on the same wifi network using local Ip address, it servers the content fine but **the request from React to Spring Boot fails**. So I can't login or get item data from the DB.

[iPhone: Connecting to 192.168.1.7:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EgFH.png)

[iPhone: Error Message debugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w32Br.png)

**Additional Info**

1. When the request is directly sent to the Spring Boot server, I get the correct error response.
   [iPhone: Error response from Spring Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxeLu.png)
2. Access from another laptop has failed too so it doesn't seem to be an iPhone issue.
3. Firewall is turned off.

I don't know what's causing the problem or if it's possible...

Comment: because your backend is set as localhost:8080, you need to add the  ip address here, since your phone would be calling localhost:8080 and its not accessible

Comment: Are you sure you changed from localhost to ip in CORS settings? Are you able to access the browser console on iPhone?

Comment: @Avinash Ahhh thank you, that was the problem and now it works...you are my savior!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this to your WebSecurityConfig file.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000","192.168.1.7:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","DELETE"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```